# iPhone: How to play a YouTube video in a certain view (instead of fullscreen)

Tags: ios, video, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I found a lots posts about playing mp4 in MPMoviePlayerController (can be in a smaller view in screen) or play youtube video in YTMoviePlayer (fullscreen). I'd like to know if there are someways to play a YouTube video in a certain view? Like apple's example code for MPMoviePlayerController?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You should try this. [LBYoutubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView). This allows you to play a video in specific view frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an iPhone, there's no way of using the MPMoviePlayerController other than fullscreen. With the iPad, it's a different story, you can embed the player in another view.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no problem in showing a MPMoviePlayerController on a view that is not using the entire screen (no matter if using the iPhone or an iPad). This is working fine since iOS 4.0. Additionally, the MPMoviePlayerController can NOT be used for playing YouTube videos.

Comment: @Till thanks for commenting, do you mean MPMoviePlayerController can be in a view but cannot play YouTube video, so Youtube video still cannot be played in a view?

Comment: @Till could you give some links about it, which works with youtube videos? thanks

Comment: @Till is right. You can show MPMoviePlayerController without utilising the entire screen, see example in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352413/ios4-mpmovieplayercontroller-embedding.